# Difference of closure of subsets.

Tags: general-topology

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are subsets of $X$ such that $C\subset B\subset A$. I'm asking under what conditions on $A, B, C$ or $X$ do I have that $\Big(cl(A)-cl(B)\Big)\cup cl(C))$ is closed in $X$ (Here $cl$ is the closure operator taken with respect to the space $X$). I know that $\Big(cl(A)-cl(B)\Big) \subset cl(A-B)$ so maybe an easier question to solve this problem would be when do we have this equality  $\Big(cl(A)-cl(B)\Big) = cl(A-B)$ and where do the missing points  $ cl(A-B)-\Big(cl(A)-cl(B)\Big)$ lie exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The relation you are seeking is $(\overline{A\setminus B})\setminus \overline{B}=\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}$.

$$A\setminus B\subseteq A\Rightarrow \overline{A\setminus B}\subseteq \overline{A}\Rightarrow(\overline{A\setminus B})\setminus \overline{B}\subseteq \overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}$$
$$\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\setminus B}\Rightarrow(\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B})\setminus \overline{B}\subseteq(\overline{A\setminus B})\setminus \overline{B}\Rightarrow\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}\subseteq(\overline{A\setminus B})\setminus \overline{B}$$

One suffient condition for $(\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B})\cup \overline{C}$ to be closed is when
$\overline{A\setminus B}\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$, which is equivalent to saying that $B$ is both open and closed in $A$. Under this condition, we have $\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}=\overline{A\setminus B}$, which is closed. Finding a necessary and sufficient condition is much more complicated because we have no idea where $C$ lies in $B$.

Comment: Please use the notation $A\setminus B$ instead of $A-B$.

Comment: While I too prefer `\setminus`, especially with these overlines, using a minus sign for set subtraction isn't without precedent.